# Why is my manifest file not generated during a TFS build?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, manifest

I have a project that uses some legacy COM components. When I included them as references in the project, I set the Isolated property to True to remove the need to register the COM components.

When I debug on my development machine Visual Studio will generate app.exe.manifest in the bin folder. This includes all the COM registry information as expected.

When I force a build from TFS, this manifest is nowhere to found. Why not?

Comment: Because those COM components are not registered on the build server would be my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a pretty bizarre scenario where MSBuild could not find the Interop assemblies and would not generate a manifest file for components it could not load.
For a while, the solution was compiling, which was weird. Eventually, the builds failed because of duplicate GUIDs for each of the project assemblies. Apparently this GUID is only used when there are COM references are in the project. After making all the project GUIDs unique, the project compiles and works on the build server. Not sure why the GUIDs were not uniquely created in the first place.